# Pseudocode Translation

Tags: c++, .net, c, compiler-construction, pseudocode

I started working just a few hours ago on a pseudocode translator, which will translate a specific pseudocode, reguarding work with stacks and queues, to c/c++ executable code. The translator has education propuses.

I am still designing the project.

I've started thinking about how this could be done; I figured that maybe the best way to do this is to, in the first place, analize the pseudocode, change it to make it c/c++ code and then compiling it to make it an exe.

NOW, this would mean that the client machine SHOULD HAVE a c/c++ compiler installed on it.

As I'm working with .NET clases ( `System.Collections.Generic.Queue(Of T)` and `System.Collections.Generic.Stack(Of T)` ), I thought that a solution to this would be to use the same compiler visual studio uses to compile c/c++ code.

I've been investigating about this proccess, and as far as I know, the only way to compile c/c++ code by using a visual studio tool, is executing cl.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt. I found that information here at [MSDN (article about how to manually compiling a c/c++ program)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk21sfcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So my first question is: does the USER versión of .NET Framework (this means, assuming the user DOES NOT have Visual Studio) include a c/c++ compiler? If yes, is it the same included in visual studio, cl.exe? How can I get access to it? If no, is there a free compiler WITHOUT IDE I can include on my translator setup?

Notice that here we're talking about transforming a pseudocode string to executable c/c++ code here, the output string MUST BE COMPILED FROM THE USER PC, that's what the project is about.

Comment: Fortunately, it appears that [a pseudocode-to-C compiler](http://forum.pellesc.de/index.php?topic=3385.0) already exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no compiler included in the .Net framework - it is for running binary files produced by the compiler.

It's possible to get the compiler for free through for example the Visual Studio Express free download scheme. There are some license limitations on that ("no commercial use", if I remember correctly - so that would mean that if one of your customers uses your product, they can no sell the resulting code they have produced [and still be within the contract with MS]). Unfortunately, this isn't "without IDE", but the compiler that is part of the download is usable without the IDE, so if "without IDE" is simply that you want to be able to run the compiler with your program, then it will work.

If you really need a package that contains the compiler (in .Net variant) but no IDE code, then you will have to find a different solution - and for .Net I'm not sure there is one. The DDK (Device Driver Kit) contains the native C and C++ compilers. But it won't, as far as I understand, produce .Net code [I could be wrong].

Edit: It seems like if you are writing your own code, you can compile it using [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) - however, this is not the same as a command-line compiler of `cl.exe`.

Comment: You're wrong- .NET ships [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) which can do this.

Comment: That's not a `cl.exe` tho'.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, I thought the OP was asking for a C# compiler.

Comment: There are no license limitations on commercial use of cl.exe included in VC++ Express. At least, nothing that explicitly prohibits such usage.

Comment: Ok, there used to be such a limitation some years back. I haven't looked into it recently.

Comment: Guys, I'm really thankful for your help, I can't vote up because I signed up just yesterday... however, C# is still an option, the source pseudocode I'm working with is very similar to C# code, I can manage to translate it to C#. I'll try that and come back if there are any issues. Really, REALLY thankful!

Answer (score 0):

The long, the short, and the ugly is "no". The only C++ compiler remotely suitable for inclusion as a library is Clang, it's free and not toooooo bad to work with, and you'll have to write your own .NET binding, and don't forget to have fun with providing your own linker and stdlib.